# Solucionar error de aplicación

Tags: nodejs

He creado una aplicación heroku para hacer una página nightscout, y a la hora de abrir la aplicación de da error H10.
He intentado cambiar caracteres del code, de las cadenas mongo, pero no funciona. Tampoco tengo mucha idea programación. Me podéis ayudar a solucionarlo, por favor? Gracias.

Comment: Bienvenida. Necesitas crear un [mre] sino será difícil responderte.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.